# How to find position from combination index

Tags: c++, math, combinations, permutation

Please bear with me for a moment as I try to explain what I would like to accomplish. I have a configuration of n terms. Each term in this configuration can have any number of elements that differ from each other. For example:

```
term1 = ["hello", "greetings", "heya"] // 3 elements
term2 = ["is", "are", "you", "wow"] // 4 elements
term3 = ["doing", "now"] // 2 elements
```

As you can see, each term has a different number of elements. I can calculate the total number of combinations by doing:

```
totalSize = term1.size * term2.size * term3.size
```

I would like to be able to automatically get the configuration by specifying the position. Say I have a total of 1000 possible combinations, I would like to find out which combination of terms position 500 would get me.

Right now I am looping through the entire thing to get to that position; this is inefficient.

Any suggestions or insight would be much appreciated,

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi Jack, and welcome to the site! Nothing about this question seems to be specific to C++. Is there a reason you added that tag?

Comment: I was hoping that I could find an implementation to my problem in C++

Comment: Ah, it would be useful to mention that in the question then. Though people might respond to your question better if it seems like you're just looking for a description of an algorithm. Sometimes when it looks like you're just looking for a code sample to copy and paste, people get the impression that you're being lazy (regardless of whether that's really true) and they can be reluctant to help.

Comment: I added the C++ flag as I thought this was more of a coding-oriented question; I couldn't find any generic "programming" tags - so I went with the language that I know best.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's up to you whether you want to ask for C++ code, or ask for a general approach to the problem. You could ask the question either way. I'm just saying that right now it's not clear which you're asking. If you do want to ask for a general approach, there's no need for a question to have a tag for a programming language or a generic tag at all; you could just remove the C++ tag and it would be fine. But if you want a generic tag, I'd suggest [tag:language-agnostic] and/or [tag:algorithm].

Comment: It might help to think of it as a multi-digit number where each digit is a different base (term1 base 3, term2 base 4, term3 base2), and the different "digits" are your strings.

Answer (score 1):

To meaningfully assign a number to each combination, one needs to choose an ordering schema. Since there are many combinations and each valid ordering is simply a permutation of every possible combination, there are lots of possible ways to order such combinations. One possible ordering could work as follows:

---

Input: a list of three strings s1, s2, and s3 each from term1, term2, and term3 respectively.

Output: a unique integer between 0 and 23, or the sizes of term1, term2 and term3 multiplied.

- set x = 0
- term1:

  - if s1 = "hello", add 0 to x
  - if s1 = "greetings", add 1 to x
  - if s1 = "heya", add 2 to x
- term2:

  - multiply x by 3, the size of term1
  - if s2 = "is", add 0 to x
  - if s2 = "are", add 1 to x
  - if s2 = "you", add 2 to x
  - if s2 = "wow", add 3 to x
- term3:

  - multiply x by 4, the size of term2
  - if x = "doing", add 0 to x
  - if x = "now", add 1 to x
- return x

---

To generate a list of strings from term1, term2, and term3 from a given number is simply the inverse of this problem. Here's a description of such an algorithm:

---

Input: a number x

Output: a triple of strings s1, s2, and s3 each from term1, term2, and term3 respectively

- s3:

  - let i = x mod 2, the size of term3
  - set s3 = term3[i]
  - set x = (x - i) / 2
- s2:

  - let i = x mod 4, the size of term2
  - set s2 = term2[i]
  - set x = (x - 1) / 4
- s1:

  - let i = x mod 3, the size of term1
  - set s3 = term1[i]
- return (s1,s2,s3)

---

Obviously, that's quite easy to implement. I'll do you and future readers a favour by writing a generalized version which accepts any number of arrays of strings. Note that the terms are used in reverse order from the above description, while still generating a unique list for every number.

```
vector<string> getCombination(const vector<vector<string>>& terms, long x){
    vector<string> result;
    for (const auto& term : terms){
        const long i = x % term.size();
        result.push_back(term[i]);
        x = (x - i) / term.size();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Example usage:

```
vector<vector<string>> terms {
    {"hello", "greetings", "heya"},
    {"is", "are", "you", "wow"},
    {"doing", "now"}
};

getCombination(terms, 0);  // -> hello is doing
getCombination(terms, 1);  // -> greetings is doing
getCombination(terms, 2);  // -> heya is doing
...
getCombination(terms, 12); // -> hello is now
...
getCombination(terms, 22); // -> greetings wow now
getCombination(terms, 23); // -> heya wow now
```

Comment: Essentially this is representation of combination number in mixed radix numeral system